# Pattern matching against type-member with Aux-pattern

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference, type-safety, aux-pattern

Consider:

```
sealed trait A

case object B extends A
case object C extends A
case object D extends A

sealed trait Test {
  type AA <: A
  val aa: AA
}

object Test {
  type Aux[AAA <: A] = Test { type AA = AAA }
}

def compilesOk(t: Test) = t.aa match {
  case _: B.type =>
    println("B")
  case _: C.type =>
    println("C")
  case _: D.type =>
    println("D")
}

def compileError(t: Test) = t.aa match {
  case B => println("B")
  case C => println("C")
  case D => println("D")
}
```

The `compileError` function fails to compile with the following error:

```
Error:(47, 10) pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : B.type
 required: t.AA
    case B => println("B")
Error:(48, 10) pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : C.type
 required: t.AA
    case C => println("C")
Error:(49, 10) pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : D.type
 required: t.AA
    case D => println("D")
```

I don't really understand the incompatibility error. All `B`, `C` and `D` are instances of `A`, what's wrong with it and why the `compilesOk` function compiles fine?

Comment: In Scala 3 this compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fYDwivfETF2GknlRUsHUig

Comment: @DmytroMitin Looks like one more gap of type member semantic in Scala 2. Thanks.