# Type inferece problem for case class with type member

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference, type-safety, aux-pattern

Consider the following example:

```
sealed trait Kind

case object B extends Kind
case object C extends Kind

sealed trait Test {
  type K <: Kind
  val kind: K
}

object Test {
  type Aux[KK <: Kind] = Test { type K = KK }
}

sealed trait Suite{
  type K <: Kind
  val kind: K
  val tests: List[Test.Aux[K]]
}

def runSuite(suite: Suite): Unit = {
  suite.kind match {
    case _: B.type =>
      val tests: List[Test.Aux[B.type]] = suite.tests
      //
    case _: C.type =>
      val tests: List[Test.Aux[C.type]] = suite.tests
      //
  }
}
```

It looks naturally, but it doesn't compile:

```
Error:(47, 51) type mismatch;
 found   : List[Test.Aux[suite.K]]
    (which expands to)  List[Test{type K = suite.K}]
 required: List[Test.Aux[B.type]]
    (which expands to)  List[Test{type K = B.type}]
        val tests: List[Test.Aux[B.type]] = suite.tests
Error:(50, 51) type mismatch;
 found   : List[Test.Aux[suite.K]]
    (which expands to)  List[Test{type K = suite.K}]
 required: List[Test.Aux[C.type]]
    (which expands to)  List[Test{type K = C.type}]
        val tests: List[Test.Aux[C.type]] = suite.tests
```

I replaced it with `asInstanceOf` workaround:

```
def runSuite(suite: Suite): Unit = {
  suite.kind match {
    case _: B.type =>
      val tests: List[Test.Aux[B.type]] = suite.tests.asInstanceOf[List[Test.Aux[B.type]]]
      //
    case _: C.type =>
      val tests: List[Test.Aux[C.type]] = suite.tests.asInstanceOf[List[Test.Aux[C.type]]]
      //
  }
}
```

And it compiles fine. Is the `asInstanceOf` safe here and it's just another problem of `Scala 2` type member semantics or there is another reason behind it?

Comment: Doesn't compile in Scala 3 either https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/rOnzAKywSjKc1j2rIkVuXg Previous OP's question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65176310/pattern-matching-against-type-member-with-aux-pattern

Comment: @pedrofurla Please put answers in answers, not comments. That way you can put the code in the answer rather than linking to code, which is discouraged.

Comment: @tim there, removed it altogether. I keep forgetting that SO is no place for dialog. My apologies.